# How to calculate High Order Moments?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moments, feature-engineering

I have a raw data set for Radio Signals (type: complex) and I want to calculate the High Order Moments and Cumulants ([see this paper PART: II-A](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.04578.pdf))

In the Paper a `Moment(p,q)`is defined as following:
[image]

I tried to look if there is any implementation of it in python but I only find the `K-th centered moment`. Also I found an implementation that I did not understand:

```
def moment(sample, p, q):     #sample is an array of complex values
    m = np.mean((sample**(p-q)) * (np.conjugate(sample)**q))
    return m
```

and before computing the moments he do the following:

```
sample = sample/np.power(moment(sample, 2,1), 0.5)
```

**Questions**

Can you explain me the difference between `M(p,q)` and `K-th centered moment`?

Is the shown implementation of `M(p,q)` is correct?

What is the reason of recomputing the samples using `M(,2,1)`?

Comment: What is the defn of $x*$?

Comment: as far as I understood it is the `conjugate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centered moment is something like $\mu_k=E[(x-\bar x)^k]$, while uncentered moment doesn't subtract the mean $M_k=E[x^k]$

Since you deal with complex quantities, you have to adjust the equations so they produce scalar values, not complex, e.g. you can't simply say $x^2$ anymore with complex numbers, you do $x^*x$, where $x^*$ is the conjugate of $x$. So, you don't have simple $M_k$ anymore, for complex quantities it turns into $M_{k,q}=E[x^{k-q}(x^*)^q]$

Here's a simple example. Take a complex number $x=a+ib$, its square is a complex number: $x^2=a^2-b^2+i(a+b)$.

However, 
with a conjugate it becomes real: $x^*x=(a-ib)(a+ib)=a^2+b^2$